# Plot option Filling conflicts with option PlotLabels

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling, filling

**Bug introduced in 10.4.0, and fixed in 11.0.0**

*`PlotLabels` is new in 10.4.0.*

---

The regulars here discuss approaches to numerically unstable systems of higher-order PDEs, and I cannot even paint by numbers … (sigh)

A Plot[] of simple curves with `Filling` and `Placed[]` labels fails. The following example works, producing a more-or-less pretty picture:

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
 PlotLabels -> {Placed[Style["u(t)", Blue], Scaled@0.18]
   (*,Placed[Style["i(t) [A]",Red],Scaled@0.18]*)
   }
 , Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]
```

If I uncomment the second "Placed…", I get

```
Extract::partw: Part 2 of {{{2.5645654315*10^-7,2.5645654315*10^-7},{0.00385433090651,0.00385432136328},{0.00770840535647,0.00770832901842},<<46>>,{0.642814839394,0.599450843234},<<1331>>}} does not exist. >>

Extract::partw: Part 2 of {{{2.5645654315*10^-7,2.5645654315*10^-7},{0.00385433090651,0.00385432136328},{0.00770840535647,0.00770832901842},<<46>>,{0.642814839394,0.599450843234},<<1331>>}} does not exist. >>

Extract::partw: Part 2 of {{{2.5645654315*10^-7,2.5645654315*10^-7},{0.00385433090651,0.00385432136328},{0.00770840535647,0.00770832901842},<<46>>,{0.642814839394,0.599450843234},<<1331>>}} does not exist. >>

General::stop: Further output of Extract::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Labeled::labpos: {Scaled[0.18]} is not a valid position for the placement of labels. >>
```

The resulting plot is, of course, not labelled.

What am I doing wrong? (And should I have uploaded images for the working and failing case?)

Comment: Strange, works fine without the Filling, works without the PlotLabels but doesn't work with the two combined. Looks buggy to me.

Comment: The issue isn't the Placed/Scaled part, just PlotLabels -> {"a", "b"} will cause the error but PlotLabels->"a" is fine (as noted in the question, giving one label works fine).

Comment: My bad, I am using earlier version so Mathematica did not recognize this syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with V.10.4.1 running on OS X.

The following both work as expected

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 4 π},
  Filling -> Axis]

Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 4 π},
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]]
```

but

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 4 π},
  PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above],
  Filling -> Axis]
```

fails to produce any filling and emits the message

[image: msg]

I say this is a bug and have tagged the question with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).

#### Update

I reported this problem to Wolfram tech support and received an answer. I quote from the relevant part:

> It does appear that combining PlotLabels and Filling would causes error, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided.

Therefore, we may take it that the [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) tag is officially blessed.

Comment: Thank you very much for narrowing this down and confirming; I appreciate your trouble.